# R Markdown - opt_hooks not exported

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I am completely new to R markdown but everytime I try to knit and creat an html file it gives me this error

Error: 'opts_hooks' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'
Execution halted

Can someone please help me? I have installed the knitr package but I don't know how to export opt_hooks.

Comment: Are you running this through Rstudio? works very well for me

Comment: Yes I am @RichardTelford

Comment: Does the example rmarkdown file work?

Comment: Try install the GitHub version of knitr.

Comment: your title says `opt_hooks`, your error message says `opts_hooks`. Which is it ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue, i guess this is an update of rmarkdown/rstudio button (didn't check) because this workaround works fine :

```
# to md
knit("myRmarkdown.Rmd")
# to html
knit2html("myRmarkdown.md")
```

Hope it helps.

PS: session info dump :

```
> devtools::session_info()
```

> Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    setting  value
>    version  R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
>    system   x86_64, linux-gnu
>    ui       RStudio (0.99.902)
>    language (EN)
>    collate  fr_FR.UTF-8
>    tz       Europe/Paris
>
> Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    package         * version    date       source
>    devtools          1.8.0      2015-05-09 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
>    knitr           * 1.11       2015-08-14 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
>    rmarkdown         0.9.6      2016-05-01 CRAN (R 3.2.0)